# Galois cover with reverse ramification data

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

Let $Y\to X$ be a Galois cover of complex varieties (or only consider complex algebraic curves) with the ramification data $(p_\bullet,\eta_\bullet)$, namely branch points $p_\bullet$ with a *preferred generator* $\eta_i$ of the stabilizer $G_{g_i}$ for each $p_i$. (To be precise, the preferred generator is the one corresponding to the monodromy of the simple counter-clock circle around the branch point.)

We know that, there is another Galois cover $Y’\to X$ with the reverse ramification data $(p_\bullet,\eta_\bullet^{-1})$.

**My question is: is there any nature $X$-morphism between these two Galois covers? If so, What can we say about it?**

More generally, what if we take the ramification data $(p_\bullet,\eta_\bullet^{m_\bullet})$ (where $m_\bullet$ are integers)?

Comment: Looking at the map induced on $\pi_1(Y) \to \pi_1(Y')$, there should be a self map of $G$ taking $\eta_i \to \eta_i^{-1}$. Such a map is available if $G$ is abelian, for example (in which case $Y$ is isomorphic to $Y'$) but may also exist otherwise. I think this should also be sufficient, using the Galois correspondence on $X \setminus \{p_\bullet\}$, but I don't have a quick argument.